# What are some good ways to avoid force unwrap, if I have already perform conditional check on that Optional?

Tags: ios, swift

It is common for me, to ensure the string is both not null, and not empty after trimming, before performing any operation. That's why I need to provide the following global function.

```
extension String
{
    func trim() -> String
    {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}

public static func isNullOrEmpty(_ string: String?) -> Bool {
    guard let s = string, !s.trim().isEmpty else {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

---

Most of the time, I will end up with code, which requires me to perform force unwrap, even though we are pretty sure the Optional cannot be nil, after `isNullOrEmpty` check.

```
public static func jsonToMutableChecklists(_ checklistPlainBody: String?) -> [Checklist] {
    if (isNullOrEmpty(checklistPlainBody)) {
        // Return a mutable list, not immutable list
        return []
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        //
        // Is it possible to avoid "checklistPlainBody!" ?
        //
        let checklists = try decoder.decode([Checklist].self, from: checklistPlainBody!.data(using: .utf8)!)
        return checklists
    } catch {
        Log.d("%@", "\(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

---

To me, force unwrap gives me a strong hint, that my code required improvement? I was wondering, is it better if I write it the following way, to avoid force unwrap on function input parameter?

```
public static func unwrapIfNotEmpty(_ string: String?) -> String? {
    guard let s = string, !s.trim().isEmpty else {
        return nil
    }

    return string
}

public static func jsonToMutableChecklists(_ checklistPlainBody: String?) -> [Checklist] {
    guard let string = unwrapIfNotEmpty(checklistPlainBody) else {
        return []
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let checklists = try decoder.decode([Checklist].self, from: string.data(using: .utf8)!)
        return checklists
    } catch {
        Log.d("%@", "\(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Comment: If the string cannot be `nil` why is the input parameter optional at all?

Comment: `pretty sure the Optional cannot be nil`. If this is the case then why use Optional String? Why not simply use a String?

Comment: I rephrase - pretty sure the Optional cannot be nil, after isNullOrEmpty check.

Comment: Ok, then your second example is perfectly fine. You can even avoid  to force unwrap the `Data` object with `Data(string.utf8)`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `Optional` extension called `mapNotEmpty` (I think the name can be improved...):

```
extension Optional where Wrapped == String {
    func mapNotEmpty() -> String? {
        return self.flatMap { $0.trim() == "" ? nil : $0 }
    }
}
```

Basically, it returns the same string if it is neither nil nor empty, otherwise it returns nil.

You can use it with a guard statement to get a non nil string:

```
public static func jsonToMutableChecklists(_ checklistPlainBody: String?) -> [Checklist] {
    guard let plainBody = checklistPlainBody.mapNotEmpty() else {
        // Return a mutable list, not immutable list
        return []
    }

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    do {
        let checklists = try decoder.decode([Checklist].self, from: plainBody.data(using: .utf8)!)
        return checklists
    } catch {
        Log.d("%@", "\(error)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do code like below

```
extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }

    var unwrap : String? {
        if self.trim().isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        return self.trim()
    }
}
```

### **Case checks**

Case 1 - param is nil

```
var checklistPlainBodyNil : String? = nil
if let unwrapString = checklistPlainBodyNil?.unwrap {
    print("checklistPlainBodyNil", unwrapString)

    // Do your code here.
}
else {
    print("checklistPlainBodyNil : String is empty or nil")
}
```

Case 2 - param is blank

```
var checklistPlainBodyBlank : String? = ""
if let unwrapString = checklistPlainBodyBlank?.unwrap {
    print("checklistPlainBodyBlank", unwrapString)

    // Do your code here.
}
else {
    print("checklistPlainBodyBlank : String is empty or nil")
}
```

Case 3 - param have value

```
var checklistPlainBodyValue : String? = "Hello, World!"
if let unwrapString = checklistPlainBodyValue?.unwrap {
    print("checklistPlainBodyValue", unwrapString)

    // Do your code here.
}
else {
    print("checklistPlainBodyValue : String is empty or nil")
}
```

### **Outputs**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the code you added in the question, you're force *unwrapping* both `checklistPlainBody` as well as the `data` you got after converting `checklistPlainBody`.

You cannot avoid unwrapping `optionals` in both of them. But, using *force unwrapping* is ofcourse not a very good solution.

You can simply create a *computed property* in `extension String` that returns the `String's` value after trimming like,

```
extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }

    var value: String? {
        return self.trim().isEmpty ? nil : self.trim()
    }
}
```

Next, the `jsonToMutableChecklists(_:)` method must be written like,

```
public static func jsonToMutableChecklists(_ checklistPlainBody: String?) -> [String] {
    if let data = checklistPlainBody?.value?.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            let checklists = try JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: data)
            return checklists
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    return []
}
```

The above code handles both unwrapping of `checklistPlainBody` and the `data` gracefully.

Comment: No idea on downvote. To me, it seems reasonable proposed solution.